# Want to give values to Alphabets and them Calculate them

Tags: macros

I have given values to the alphabets in Arabic, but I will give example of English alphabets, as both will work the same way, obviously.

A =1 B=2 and so on...

Now I want the Macro to find all As, Bs etc... in the desired cell and then calculate the numbers.

Comment: Are you refering to Excel?

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to Excel.

Comment: I have a theory for it. I find no issues in it, but the actual problem is that I am unable to figure after giving values to all these alphabets, how will I command VBA to find each count(s) of the Alphabets and calculate them further. The only issue, so far, (in my theory) is that how will I be able to find the alphabets counts as then calculating them should not be a problem. Or, will be kinder and let me know if this is not as easy as I am thinking of?

Comment: I must let you know, that there are a couple of (if not tens of) software and Android apps which are able to do this like Abjad Calculator.apk and Qurangematria.exe and almost all of these are for free and reachable, but I want to work in excel due to many reasons.